# How to create a listview as iphone contact in android?

Tags: android, iphone, listview, android-listview

I really want to  create a custom listview as Contacts of iPhone which contains many sub-listviews, each sub-listview has a title. When we scroll it, the title will be anchored at the top of parent-listview until all rows of sub-listview go over. is there any sample code for this?

[image]

[image]

> The title is anchored at the top of listview (or scrollview) untill
>   the image is scrolled over.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the android contacts app, there is this listview you meant ;)

[Link to source code on CyanogenMod's GitHub](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Contacts/blob/gingerbread/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it isn't clearly. I added some image to my question above, Hope you understand my question.